# How to troubleshoot a dying resque process

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.x application with Resque. I run the resque command with:

```
nohup rake RAILS_ENV=production environment resque:work QUEUE='*' & >>/tmp/resque.log 2>> /tmp/resque.err.log
```

Every other day the process dies, but the two output files are always empty. Any other way of figuring out why the Resque process goes down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the super awesome [Pry console](https://github.com/pry/pry). This is similar to `irb` only much more advanced.

You can use `binding.pry` inside your `perform` method or preferably in a [hook](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/blob/master/docs/HOOKS.md) which will start up a pry console using which you can debug. Helped me in similar situations a lot.